# Need help proving $h$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Here's the problem:

Define $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

[image]

Prove $h$ is continuous at $0$.

Usually, I have a good idea how to prove this when the cases are $x=0$ and $x\neq0$, but I'm a bit thrown off here since it says $x$ is rational/irrational. Can someone help explain this problem to me?

I think I'm supposed to use $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Take $\varepsilon$ and set $\delta:=\varepsilon$.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to apply the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), although the direct approach suggested by Git Gud should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left|x\sin\frac1x\right|\le|x|\to 0$$

Comment: Let me see if I understand how you got that. Since $\sin({\frac{1}{x}})$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, you can multiply the inequality by $x$ to get that?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19 Well, yes though in fact I did use properties of the absolute value: $$\left|x\sin\frac1x\right|=|x|\,\left|\sin\frac1x\right|\le|x|$$

Comment: Okay, so after this step, since $x \to 0$ can we say $x < \delta$ and work out the rest of the proof from there?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19 Indeed so...or apply directly the squeeze theorem, of course.

Comment: Thanks! Could you help explain how I would use the Squeeze Theorem? It would be nice to know both ways in this case.

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19 Just as shown! Observe that the inequality $\;0\le\;$ *on the left* is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You could equivalently use sequential continuity: show that for all $a_n\to 0$, we have $h(a_n)\to h(0)=0$. Using the fact that $|\sin|\leq 1$, this shouldn't be too hard.